# Modal Bottom sheet not becoming full screen

Tags: android, material-components-android, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I want a modal bottom sheet to fill the entire screen minus a custom offset. This is my code:

```
<style name="Widget.App.HuddlePostBottomSheet" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/Widget.App.HuddlePostBottomSheet.Modal</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.App.HuddlePostBottomSheet.Modal" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/colorSurface</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.HuddlePostBottomSheet</item>
    <item name="behavior_fitToContents">false</item>
    <item name="behavior_skipCollapsed">false</item>
    <item name="behavior_draggable">true</item>
    <item name="behavior_expandedOffset">120dp</item>
    <item name="shouldRemoveExpandedCorners">false</item>
</style>
```

And I have overriden the onCreateDialog() method in the fragment:

```
class HuddlePostFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL,R.style.Widget_App_HuddlePostBottomSheet)
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog =  super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
        if (dialog is BottomSheetDialog) {
            dialog.behavior.apply {
                isFitToContents = false
                state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            }
        }
        return dialog
    }
}
```

This is my layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        // UI goes here

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

With this, I expect the layout to fill the expanded bottom sheet, but what I get is this:

[image]

I noticed in the layout inspector that the `FrameLayout` that holds the bottom sheet is still wrap_content. Is there a way to fix this?

I saw some answers suggest using `findViewById()` to get the `FrameLayout`, but I don't want to do that because the id might change in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd set the bottom sheet height to `MATCH_PARENT` programmatically during fragment lifecycle `onViewCreated()` or `onStart()` callbacks:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
    val parentLayout =
        (dialog as BottomSheetDialog)
            .findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)

    parentLayout?.let { bottomSheet ->
    
        // set the bottom sheet height to match_parent
        val layoutParams = bottomSheet.layoutParams
        layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        bottomSheet.layoutParams = layoutParams

    }
}
```

This won't affect the offset value defined in the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` style.

---

**Edit**

> I am just a little bit apprehensive of the
> com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet. Is there a
> cleaner way to do it? I checked the github issues section but I
> couldnt find any discussion about exposing a setting to change it.

I'm not sure if they would do that for some reason; if they did so, that would dramatically change the lives of many developers :). Anyway, you'd use the `view` parameter passed in the `onViewCreated` instead:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
     (view.parent as View).layoutParams.apply {
          height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, That works. I am just a little bit apprehensive of the com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet. Is there a cleaner way to do it? I checked the github issues section but I couldnt find any discussion about exposing a setting to change it.

Comment: @ShahiM, You'd use the fragment `view` instead; just edited the answer, please have a look